# How to reset database after each test when using jeeunit?

Tags: java, testing, jakarta-ee

I was wondering if there is anyone who have had success in clearing out database contents before each test when using jeeunit (or any other java ee application test framework)?

I've tried using the @Transactional annotation as described in jeeunit documentation where it will rollback all transactions done. However there are cases (session is flushed) where the changes done is persisted between tests, causing test pollution.

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Try looking at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110726/database-base-unit-testing-strategy-truncating-tables-between-unit-tests-test

Comment: I was hoping to stick with the existing test framework...

Comment: A flush() does not commit a transaction, so I suspect the problem must be somewhere else, but this is hard to tell unless you provide more context. Can you attach a test case to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/jeeunit/issues/detail?id=20)?

Comment: It was a short term project i was on that had a huge legacy codebase. I no longer have access to the source code, so im sorry if i can't give you more details. However it was container managed beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use jeeunit with h2 db and forcibly delete all rows in database through native SQL before each test.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned 'any other java ee application test framework' I would recommend looking into Arquillian Persistence Extension for unit testing a Java EE application. You can find a tutorial on how to use it here: http://www.softwarepassion.com/java-ee-6-testing-with-arquillian-persistence-extension/

More info about arquillian itself [here](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian)

Comment: Is using an alpha version the best idea?

Comment: Snapshot of Version 1.0 final is already available: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence

Comment: But what really stands for Alpha? That it's all broken? In my eyes it means that it obviously may contain bugs, but it's open for community to shape its direction in terms of API and features.

Answer (score 0):

DBUnit is designed to assist with this exact problem - their website is [here](http://www.dbunit.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework 's AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests is another good beginning.

And you can do it yourself by set autoCommit(false) before execute on your connection, and rollback after your code run.